# Ошибка в инструкции SQL - пропущен символ ;

Tags: sql, access

Мне нужно добавить несколько записей в таблицу. Если добавлять одну запись, то всё нормально. А если, как минимум, две, то пишет, что пропущена точка с запятой.
Вот запрос:

```
INSERT INTO Изделие ( название, вес, колличество, цена, дата_изготовления, фирма_изготовитель )
VALUES 
('Название1', 1.1, 1, 1.1, 2001/01/01, 'фирма1'),
('Название2', 2.2, 2, 2.2, 2002/02/02, 'фирма2');
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Насколько я могу судить по [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql), такой синтаксис не поддерживается. Для вставки сразу несколько значений нужно писать `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...`

Answer (score 1):

1. Из известных мне СУБД, только MySQL позволяет одним запросом добавлять несколько записей. Во всех остальных нужно для каждой записи писать свой запрос.
2. Дату в запросе нужно обрамлять символами `#` иначе вы просто получаете операцию деления.
3. Использовать кириллические названия в именах полей и таблиц крайне нежелательно. Или, по крайней мере, их нужно обрамлять символами `[...]`
4. В слове `количество` - одна буква `л`

Итого получается

```sql
INSERT INTO [Изделие] (
  [название], [вес], [количество], [цена], [дата_изготовления], [фирма_изготовитель]
) VALUES (
  'Название1', 1.1, 1, 1.1, #2001/01/01#, 'фирма1'
);

INSERT INTO [Изделие] (
  [название], [вес], [количество], [цена], [дата_изготовления], [фирма_изготовитель]
) VALUES (
  'Название2', 2.2, 2, 2.2, #2002/02/02#, 'фирма2'
);
```

Comment: Я пробовал вот так несколько команд писать. Пишет: "Обнаружены символы за пределами инструкции SQL.".

Comment: @АндрійАфонченко Где пробовали? Может то место где вы пробовали не позволяет выполнять несколько запросов?

Comment: Мне нужно в Microsoft Access.

Comment: можно добавлять несколько записей [в MS SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff6b8/19102)

Comment: @АндрійАфонченко - из какой среды выполняете запросы? Используете какой-то язык программирования (C#, VB.NET) или в самом Access вводите? В первом случае выполняйте отдельные запросы-команды на вставку, во втором случае смотрите https://stackoverflow.com/a/65027/5045688